# Usage of "inciting/instigating against" in a sentence

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction

Can I rewrite this sentence:

> > "Ronald thought that Tom is inciting/instigating hatred against him in John."

as:

> > "Ronald thought that Tom is inciting/instigating John against him."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure your first sentence is idiomatic, but putting that aside.  The [dictionary says you may](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/incite) use incite/instigate with a person as the direct object.

> He incited **loyal subjects** to rebellion

Personally, I prefer the action to be the object:

> He incited **rebellion** in the king's loyal subjects

But your sentence would seem to be fine.  "Instigate" is the same.  With either, I would be more clear about what specific action the subject is inciting/instigating.

> Tom instigated John **to dislike** Ronald.

What bothers me most about the first sentence is that it's a complicated and roundabout way to say something for which there is a common idiom:

> Ronald thinks John is **turning John against him**.

Comment: I phrased the first sentence by using following 2 example sentences from Oxford website as a reference: 
"This ‘knowledge’ is often designed to foster hatred and to incite violence and hostility against us.", 
‘She said it showed a desire to incite hatred and violence against non-British citizens, even if those fantasies had never been acted out.’

Comment: @abhijeetpathak  Your first sentence is *grammatical*, but not necessarily *natural* English.  Let me think about what exactly sounds wrong, and I'll edit my answer.

Comment: By any chance did you get time to look at this.

Comment: @abhijeetpathak   It's a roundabout and unnecessarily complicated way to say something that has a  straightforward idiom:  *"Ronald thinks Tom is **turning John against him***.